# Disable Inline Editing of Fields in Profile Form

Tags: profile, jquery

I have created a profile where authenticated members can edit some custom fields which are part of a multivalue fieldset that I created. Everything works fine - the links to view, edit and delete all work ok. However, on the profile listings page itself the inline editing feature is not working for dropdown list custom fields, only for text and text area fields. When a user clicks on one of the dropdown fields, it simply dissappears and throws a jQuery error:

```
jquery.crmEditable.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.crmEditableEntity (jquery.crmEditable.js:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.getData (jquery.crmEditable.js:204)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jeditable.min.js:17)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?p9n09n:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js?p9n09n:3)
```

Is it possible to disable completely the inline editing for that profile form? Or perhaps for authenticated users? They can still edit the record by clicking on the edit button.

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.28 with Drupal 7.59.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was a bug in CiviCRM. I have written a fix and submitted a pull-request for review. Your testing and feedback can help expedite the review process to get it accepted into the codebase.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12312

Comment: Many thanks for looking at this. I applied the changes to the test site, and they work when logged in as an administrator, but produce another jQuery error (403 Forbidden) when not logged in as the administrator but with view, edit and delete privileges for the profile. You can see the new error at http://drupal.benmango.co.uk/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=14&reset=1&id=109. I added  a more detailed comment at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12312.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, fixing the bug would be better than working around it. Are you able to reproduce the issue on a demo site? If so you could file a bug report and we could look into it.

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back to me. I'll see if I can reproduce it and get back to you.

Comment: I have created a test site with a public proflle where you can see the error at http://drupal.benmango.co.uk/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=14&reset=1&id=109. As you will see the dropdowns don't work but the textarea does.